# Django Query filltering on ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models

I have a table which contains a list of tasks to do involving Sim cards. A task can only be done if all sims card used in the task are available at the same time

Example tasks in the table:

```
Task1 - IMEI1 & IMEI2
Task2 - IMEI1
```

If I have a list of IMEI with only IMEI1, I only want to have Task2. If I have a list with IMEI1 AND IMEI2 I want to have Task1 & Task2.

Please note I have a random number of sims in this List.

Here is my code:

```
class Sim(models.Model):
    msisdn = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=False, default='IMEI')

class taskInQueue(models.Model):
     simInvolved = models.ManyToManyField(Sim)
```

So in a `taskInQueue` I have one or more `Sim` involved in the task. In a function, I try to get all task which involve a list of sims:

```
sim = getSimInvolved(_imeiList)  #_imeiList is a list of IMEI -> Sim is a list of SIm Objects
```

First I was doing the following thing:

```
tasks = taskInQueue.objects.filter(simInvolved__in=sim, testsStatus='W').distinct().order_by('pk')
```

The problem is that, with this query, I will have all tasks which involved at least one of the sims. So if I can my previous example, with `_imeiList=['IMEI1']`, I will get Task1 & Task2 whereas I must only get Task2.

So how can I filter `taskInQueue` which have all their Involved Sims in the list `_imeiList`?

Answer (score 1):

Using chain filters?

```
tasks = taskInQueue.objects.all()
for sim in sims:
    tasks = tasks.filter(simInvolved=sim)

# in the end tasks will only contains those tasks which required all sims
```

Comment: Well, the thing is I don't know the number of IMEI I'll have in my list! It can be one, it can be two, it can three or five... So I can't use this :( That's why I'm stuck :s

Comment: Use a for loop then. I have updated the solution. How many IMEI you are expecting, maximum for a task?

Comment: Well a max of 4 Sim is expected.If I chain filters, I'll only have task with ALL sim  in the list no? So If i take the example, i'll only have have Task1